Can you make Doctrine return a fresh instance of an Entity generated from the DB than the one that was inserted?
We are upgrading a web API from:

PHP 7.4
Symfony 4.4
Doctrine 2.8

To:

PHP 8.2
Symfony 5.4
Doctrine 2.19

We have a large main entity, with many Collection objects, containing other entities. We accept new instances via a POST call, with a JSON body, that gets deserialized by JMS Serializer before eventually being inserted to the database. The Collection objects are represented by JSON arrays, of course.
After inserting the main entity, we flush, refresh, and findOneBy the entity back from the DB again, to return to the client. I believe the reason for this was to get back exactly what would be returned in a future GET request. In the old version, this worked.
On our upgraded branch, we have noticed that when the POST is missing a property that that represents a Collection, the instance that we get to return to the client has null instead of an empty collection. In fact, on investigation, I find that if I === compare the instance we inserted with persist to the one returned from findOneBy, they are the same object. I would expect the intervening refresh call to prevent that, on the upgraded branch, it does not. On the old branch, we do get back an empty Collection for the property.
I have read that the official position of Doctrine is that collections should always be initialized in the constructor. That makes perfect sense to me! However, the JMS Serializer doesn't use the constructor - these objects are never constructed before being passed to Doctrine to store, they are just deserialized.
JMS Serializer, on the other hand, doesn't seem to provide any way to set a Collection as a default for a missing property, or to run a constructor.
I'm open to any suggestions, here, but I would prefer to fix this by restoring the Doctrine behavior we see on our old branch, of getting a new instance of the Entity from the DB. The reason this would be preferable is that this is already a complicated and high-risk upgrade, and I want to minimize any additional risk of something else, unanticipated, being different, and breaking our clients.
